# Momentarily Highlighting Text in .NET C# TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, textbox

I'm trying to modify the .NET C# TextBox class to implement parentheses balancing such that whenever a right parenthesis is typed (or the cursor is moved to the immediate right of one), the corresponding left parenthesis is momentarily highlighted.

To do this, I created a subclass of TextBox that is notified whenever the selection is changed:

```
public BalanceTextBox() : base()
  {         
   this.AcceptsReturn = true;
   this.IsReadOnly = false;
   this.SelectionChanged += new RoutedEventHandler(TextBoxSelectionChanged);
  }
```

The event handler calls a method which looks for the matching left parenthesis if the cursor is to the immediate right of a right parenthesis:

```
private void TextBoxSelectionChanged(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
    BalanceCheck();
   }
```

If a matching left parenthesis is found, the FlashParenthesis method is called to momentarily highlight it.

```
public void FlashParenthesis(
  int selStart,
  int selLength,
  int leftParenLocation)
  {
   this.SelectionChanged -= new RoutedEventHandler(TextBoxSelectionChanged);

   this.Select(leftParenLocation,1);
   this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(delegate { }));
   Thread.Sleep(200);
   this.Select(selStart,selLength);

   this.SelectionChanged += new RoutedEventHandler(TextBoxSelectionChanged);
  }
```

This method temporarily removes the event handler (so that it is not invoked recursively), changes the cursor selection to highlight the left parenthesis, calls Dispatcher.Invoke to force the change to be displayed, sleeps the thread momentarily so that the change can be seen, and then restores the original selection and adds back the event handler.

There are several issues with this code:

1. FlashParenthesis is correctly called whenever a ')' is typed or the cursor is moved using the arrow keys, but the matching '(' is only highlighted when using the arrow keys (and not when a ')' is typed).
2. Most of the time, the highlighting of the '(' clearly allows you to see the selection change, but around 10% to 30% of the time the highlighting only allows you to see a quick flicker.
3. The call to Dispatcher.Invoke is some voodoo I found online that forces the selection change to display. It seems like there should be a better way to do this, but I can't figure out any other way to get the code to work without this call.

The complete code for the BalanceTextBoxClass:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace BALANCE
  {
   public partial class BalanceTextBox : TextBox 
     {
      public BalanceTextBox() : base()
        {         
         this.AcceptsReturn = true;
         this.IsReadOnly = false;
         this.SelectionChanged += new RoutedEventHandler(TextBoxSelectionChanged);
        }
        
    private void TextBoxSelectionChanged(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
         BalanceCheck();
        }

    public void FlashParenthesis(
        int selStart,
        int selLength,
        int leftParenLocation)
        {
         Console.WriteLine("Balance Left Parenthesis at " + leftParenLocation);

         this.SelectionChanged -= new RoutedEventHandler(TextBoxSelectionChanged);

         this.Select(leftParenLocation,1);
         this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new Action(delegate { }));
         Thread.Sleep(200);
         this.Select(selStart,selLength);

         this.SelectionChanged += new RoutedEventHandler(TextBoxSelectionChanged);
        }
                       
    public void BalanceCheck()
        {
         char characterToCheck;
         
         if (this.Text.Length == 0)
            { return; }

         int selStart = this.SelectionStart;
         int selLength = this.SelectionLength;

         if (selLength != 0)
            { return; }

         int cursorLocation = this.CaretIndex;
         if (cursorLocation == 0) 
           { return; }

         cursorLocation--;
         characterToCheck = this.Text[cursorLocation];
         if (characterToCheck != ')')
           { return; }
         
         int nestingDepth = 1;
         while (cursorLocation-- != 0)
           {
            characterToCheck = this.Text[cursorLocation];
            
            if (characterToCheck != '(')
              {
               if (characterToCheck == ')')
                 { nestingDepth++; }
               continue; 
              }
            
            nestingDepth--;
            if (nestingDepth != 0)
              { continue; }
              
            FlashParenthesis(selStart,selLength,cursorLocation);

            return;
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Instead of involving a second thread and the Dispatcher, consider making your code `async` and `await`ing a call to `Task.Delay`. Also consider something richer than a simple text box, and using that richness to change the appearance of the parens. The problem with changing the selection is that a fast touch typist may break this

Comment: There isn't even a background thread. You must never call Thread.Sleep in the main thread of a UI application.

Comment: @Flydog57 Thanks for the suggestion. I was able to fix my issue using it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem by setting the IsReadOnlyCaretVisible property in the constructor:

```
public BalanceTextBox() : base()
  {         
   this.AcceptsReturn = true;
   this.IsReadOnly = false;
   this.IsReadOnlyCaretVisible = true;
   this.SelectionChanged += new RoutedEventHandler(TextBoxSelectionChanged);
  }
```

and then modifying FlashParenthesis to use await Task.Delay and temporarily make the TextBox read only so that the text can't be changed while the cursor is temporarily moved.

```
public async void FlashParenthesis(
  int selStart,
  int selLength,
  int leftParenLocation)
  {
   this.SelectionChanged -= new RoutedEventHandler(TextBoxSelectionChanged);

   this.IsReadOnly = true;
   this.Select(leftParenLocation,1);
   await Task.Delay(150);
   this.Select(selStart,selLength);
   this.IsReadOnly = false;

   this.SelectionChanged += new RoutedEventHandler(TextBoxSelectionChanged);
  }
```